# Ошибка при передаче sql параметра

Tags: c#, sql

Есть код, в котором должен передаться параметр stopWord.

```
using (var connection = GetDbConnection())
     {
        connection.Open();
        using (var cmd =
           new SqlCommand(
              string.Format("ALTER FULLTEXT STOPLIST [{0}] ADD @stopWord LANGUAGE [{1}];", stopWord.StopList,
                 stopWord.Language), (SqlConnection)connection))
        {
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stopWord", stopWord.StopWord);

           cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
     }
```

в качестве значения в stopWord приходит

> test's

Мне нужно экранировать спецсимволы, чтобы данные успешно добавлялись в БД.
Как это сделать, т.к. текущий код выдает следующую ошибку:

```
Incorrect syntax near '@stoplist'. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near '@stoplist'.
```

Comment: в случаях с синтаксическими ошибками в sql, не плохой практикой бывает создать процедуру на sql, которая выполнит необходимое вам действие, и потом передать туда параметры. В 90% случаев сами поймете в чем проблема. Т.е. текст запроса перенести на сторону SQL.

Comment: А какие у Вас значения остальных параметров - stopWord.StopList, stopWord.Language?

Comment: @SergeyNudnov StopList = "ForTest", Language="English" или "Russian"